# Is this market monopoly or duopoly?

Tags: microeconomics, stock-market, monopoly, competition, dominant-strategy

Could you help me to identify monopoly, because I got confused. There is a company with market share of 54 %. The second one has market share of 21 %.
Can this market be characterized as monopoly or maybe duopoly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a monopoly is one company having the exclusive control of a good or service. Since there are 2+ companies it does not fit the definition of a monopoly.

A duopoly is a situation where 2 companies control the majority of the market. It sounds like this describes your situation.

A more correct term may be oligopoly which describes a market where a small limited number of entities controls the majority of the market. If there is a 3rd company which controls the remaining 25% market share this may be the most correct term but otherwise a duopoly is probably the correct definition.